# View for grid of images

Tags: ios, gridview, uiscrollview

I have an array of images, which are being displayed in a `UIScrollView`. I want only 3 images horizontally in a row, if the array contains 5 images then 3 images should be on the first row and the remaining 2 should move to next row.

If I had a string I would have used `\n` in a loop but I have an array of objects.

Comment: use a collection view

Comment: :( But I have to make it without collection view, any possibilities

Comment: Then use a tableview and make it like a gridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code

```
float xPos = 10.0f;
float yPos = 10.0f;
int lineCheck = 0;

for(int i =0; i<10;i++)
{
    if (lineCheck == 3)
    {
        lineCheck = 0;
        xPos = 10.0f;
    }
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, 100.0f, 100.0f)];
    imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YOur image name"];
    [scrollView addSubview:imgView];

    xPos = xPos+110.0f;
    yPos = yPos+110.0f;
    lineCheck = lineCheck+1;

}
```

Comment: Your code is brilliant, thanks a lot bro.

Answer (score 0):

You can [Customize Table Cells](http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/UITableView/customizing.html) and dsiplay the images as your wish.

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        // allocate the cell:
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

       //set conditions,create yourImageView's and desired frames for image view.

      [cell.contentView addSubview:yourImageView];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware this is very old but it has been implemented by me in several projects. I found `GMGridView` is one of the best, solutions for your case. Just check it  out :

1. [GMGridView](https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView)
2. [DTGridView](http://danieltull.co.uk/blog/2009/10/28/dtgridview/)
3. [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView)

Hope you would be able to implement it easily.